# Running "nodemon index.js" launches Windows Script Host instead of VS: WSH Error Code 800A03F6

Tags: javascript, windows, bash, nodemon

I'm running a node.js application and I installed nodemon.

Unfortunately, I installed it from the CMD on Windows (I keep having problems installing new packages from VS, as it doesn't update the PATH). So once I installed it from CMD, I run a command using nodemom, then Windows asked me what tool to use. I had a few choices, among them VS, but I pressed Windows Bash Script...since then even though I run nodemom from VS terminal, I got the same error as attached again and again.

I have tried to disable WBS, but I didnt find the exact Enable/Disable settings in the registry.

I tried this too: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-windows_programs/microsoft-jscript-error-800a03ea/e8723445-77ea-4b13-b13e-afde15f22bfb 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rx1sC.jpg)
I have checked the PATH and seems correct both on the user and system env variables are pointing to: ...npm\node_modules\nodemon\bin\

What else can I do?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

When I was trying to run a simple node.js express app I saw the same error message when I had the following code in my package.json:

```json
{
  ...
  "start": "nodemon --exec src/index.js",
  ...
}
```

Then Windows was also asking me which program I want to use to execute it.

**The fix for me** was to set the correct interpreter (in my case node).

```json
{
  ...
  "start": "nodemon --exec node src/index.js",
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use window and babel to compile then you can try:

```
{
  ...
  "start": "nodemon --exec ./node_modules/.bin/babel-node ./src/index.js",
  ...
}
```